# command to install java jdk latest version on kali

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, jdk

I want to do programming in `java 15` for that I need `jdk` .
What is the `command` to download latest `jdk` in `kali-linux`.

```
sudo apt install -y default-jdk
```

Is the above command will install latest jdk I am confused because I doesn't specify any `version`?

English is not my native language **excuse me please**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your use for the system is programming, then Kali isn't the distro for you. If you don't have an advanced knowledge of Linux, which it looks as though you don't, then Kali definitely isn't for you. Kali Linux is for penetration testing and is designed for those who already have an advanced knowledge of Linux. A better distro for you use would be Debian, Ubuntu, or Mint as they are all of the same family with Ubuntu and Kali being forked from Debian and Mint being forked from Ubuntu. The others are far more user friendly and better for beginners.

Comment: @NasirRiley exactly I m not looking for a desktop friendly system and purposefully chosen kali

Comment: As I stated, if you don't understand what the package manager (`apt`) does, then your knowledge of Linux isn't advanced enough to use Kali. It's not for programming and isn't nor is it for someone who lacks a basic understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kali Linux is based on Debian where `default-jdk` is a "recommended" or best Java SDK version which currently is `openjdk-11-jdk`. If you need Java 15 you need to install `openjdk-15-jdk` which (based on the Kali Linux Package Tracker) [should be available in Kali](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/openjdk-15).

Comment: https://www.javahelps.com/2019/04/install-latest-oracle-jdk-on-linux.html

Comment: Above link helped to install java latest version